# Можно ли получить освещенность объекта через Light2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d, light

Я использую Light2D для освещения и мне надо узнать насколько освещён объект или область.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой информации в памяти просто физически́ нет, всё происходит в видеокарте. Причём никакой карты освещённости, как карты глубины в `G-Buffer` не существует, всё просчитывается для каждого пикселя или вертекса индивидуально шейдером.

Для того что бы узнать, как освещено какое-то место, нужен дубль этого-же места, без посторонних объектов, которые отбрасывают лишние тени, вроде персонажей, где у всех объектов белый шейдер без текстуры для 3D объектов и специальны́й для спрайта заменяющий значения RGB на значение A и отдельно отрендерить это место.

Это не очень тяжело, но довольно много возьни с дублем. Достаточно отрендерить всего один пиксель отдельной камерой смотрящей на точку о которой нужно инфо освещенности. Цвет пикселя света нужно переводить в `HSV` и брать значение `V`, поскольку свет не обязательно белый. Дубль на слое который не рендерит основная камера и находится в том же месте. Источники света могут освещать оба места, находясь на специальном слое, который, рендарят обе камеры. В целом метод не грузный.

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, решить эту проблему непросто и *нет никакого "встроенного" метода*.

**Моя первая мысль** - это попробовать **raycasting** к источнику света, определить расстояние и оттуда рассчитать количество света.

**Второй вариант**, это своего рода карта освещения, в которой вы могли бы просто «знать» значение света, например, каждая точка будет иметь значение, и вы просто прочитаете это *0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3*